# Scripting : Mirroring an object

Tags: scripting, transforms, mirror

Its probably basic :
For every object in the scene that has "right" in its name I need to create a copy object on the left, but mirrored relative to the origin.
I tried to use the code that appear in the Info panel when I do this mirroring manually. Before I (try to ) select the object to be mirrored.
No mirroring occurs.

```
for  o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
if  "right" in o.name :
    new_left = o.copy()
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(new_left)
    new_left.name = o.name.replace("right", "left")
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = new_left
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1, -1, 1), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=0.263331, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)
```

There were some changes since 2.8, right ?

Thank you for any advice you can give me !
Nicolas

Comment: At issue here could be not also making a mesh copy, `new_left.data = new_left.data.copy()`  Otherwise transform apply will change both original and copy.  If using a mesh copy could `me.transform(S)` where `S = Matrix.Diagonal((1, -1, 1))` and set `new_left.matrix_world.transform.y *= -1`  instead of using the operators.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand; but how can I make a mesh copy ? 
 I tried but got an error :  `new_left.data = src_obj.data.copy()`

Comment: ooops ... The error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'

Comment: If the object is an empty its data is `None`  test for it.

Comment: Yes, there where some empties in the bunch. My bad. But in tour code, I don't see what me is.